# Understanding how Adobe Flash Player Garbage Collector works

Tags: flash, garbage-collection, air

Can anyone tell me how the Flash Player Garbage Collector works please?
No worry about version, even if you tell me about GC in Flash Player 8.0, 9.0, or 10.0 it does not matter.

Many articles in Adobe Connection just tell the same old things: trees, counters and indeterminacy of deallocation times... all things we know....

But how about deallocation policies? Are there pools just like CLR in .NET (well explained in MSDN) or any other particular approach? I am interested in the algorithms...

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the Flash player (at least up to 11.2) will:

- Mark an sweep objects based on any strong references
- References are tracked via DRC (Deferred Reference Counting)

The best article I've found was on JPauclair's blog which goes into details:
http://jpauclair.net/2009/12/23/tamarin-part-iii-current-garbage-collector-in-flash-10-0/

At the bottom he lists a few additional references / sources including the 3 part series by Grant Skinner.

Answer (score 0):

Grant Skinner wrote a few good articles on garbage collection and resource management. You can find them [here](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html)

Comment: Yes, these articles were usefule, I read them but still just provided few details... reference counting, sweep marking and deferred memory deallocation with just some note about heuristics on memory... is this all??? References about CLR GC in .NET are very accurate explaining in details how it works, which algorithms are used and what policies and strategies are considered...